# Editing the Session Collection disk size in Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, session

I created a  Remote Desktop Services Session Collection a few weeks ago using Windows Server 2012 R2  Standard.

I am now realizing I overdid the Maximum Size in the user profile disks section, and want to pull this  back.

However,  when editing the Session Collection, the Maximum Size (in GB) box is greyed out.

How can I edit this in order to change the disk size?

Answer (score 2):

so find the location for the default UPD (UVHD-Template.vhdx on the share for UPDS you have set up) and manually use to shrink it to the size you require (instructions are here.. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2014/01/30/shrinking-a-vhdx-on-a-running-virtual-machine.aspx).  However UPDs are dynamically expanding VHDXs so will only take up the space used.

Comment: The default UPD is very small - far smaller than the max size I want to assign. As you said, they dynamically expand, so I don't know how this would fix it...

Comment: Yes an "un-hydrated" VHDX file is very small on disk , but what I am talking about are it's properties. So if you examine form Hyper-V Manager you'll se what size it is set to and you can change this.